# How do I remove the web address in a display:standalone IOS PWA?

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to set up a standalone PWA on ios and the web address still remains

I have included the following in the `index.html`

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="mobile-wep-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

And have
included

```
    "display": "standalone"
```

in the `site.webmanifest`

The connection to our server is over https

Are there any other checklist items that need to be included to remove the url from displaying?

UPDATE - 14/05/19:

I believe the index.html and config was fine. I now believe this is an issue to do with routing

When you add a PWA to the homescreen in IOS it sets the entry URL to the PWA as the page you are currently on. In my case, when users first enter the app, they are at `www.sitename.co.uk/login`
and not at the root of the page
`www.sitename.co.uk/`

I stumbled across online that safari's full screen PWA apps will show the URL bar after a redirection to a different domain, to prevent phishing/ make the redirection clear to users.

I can only assume that, when you add the PWA, it adds the url as some sort of 'root' and when you try and navigate beneath the root it flags this up as unexpected behaviour
And causes this sort of behaviour

```
/login -> No URL
/ -> URL
/edit/resource -> URL
/login/resource -> No URL
```

This is annoying because

a) I would want the same PWA experience for a user regardless of what screen they added the app on

b) It would make far more sense to allow all routes on the domain of the PWA to be viewed without a URL.

Comment: Looks okay, maybe a stupid question, but are you sure you have included the manifest? i.e. `<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">`

Comment: Have you used the lighthouse tools to make sure your PWA is valid and will install? What version of iOS & what browser?

Comment: iOS doesn't support manifest files.

Answer (score 3):

maybe its a bit late for this, but you could try adding a `scope` attribute to your manifest. That way the address bar won't be shown on IOS as long as the host is the same specified in `scope`.

Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/scope